# Spring Data JPA @Query not working (findAll + filter works)

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, java-stream, hql

I have a custom @Query which returns 0 results when I try to filter data using HQL (should return 1 result)

```
@Query("SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...")
Set<SomeObject> find...(@Param("param") String param,...)
```

but when I use `repository.findAll()` and filter the data using streams in Java I get the result I need. FYI **I filter the data using exactly the same conditions as in the query**.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: It would be better to let us  see your query.

Comment: Also your entities considering that you use HQL

Comment: ¿Why you implement the findAll() method? It is implemented by default, try to use it

Comment: And also how you filter using the streams api.